# How to calculate a division with lag? x[-1] / x[-length(x)]

Tags: r, time-series, division

how can I calculate a division with lag 12?

Monthly data example:

- 2000-01: 179.300
- 2000-02: 179.400
- 2000-03: 180.000
- 2000-04: 180.300
- 2000-05: 180.700
- 2000-06: 181.100
- 2000-07: 181.500
- 2000-08: 181.900
- 2000-09: 182.300
- 2000-10: 182.600
- 2000-11: 183.100
- 2000-12: 183.300
- 2001-01: 183.900
- 2001-02: 184.400
- 2001-03: 184.700

Now I would lilke divide:

- Value January 2001 (183.900) / Value January 2000 (179.300)
- February 2001 (184.400) / February 2000 (179.400)
- For march: 184.700/180.000

I tried:

```
y<- x[-1] / x[-length(x)]
```

But this is a normal division for each value who is before the other one without lag.

Can I modify the formula with gap 12?

Thank you for helping.

Best regards

Comment: Can you please share a data sample as code, e.g. with the output of `dput(x)` copied into your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will assume the input data frame `DF` shown in the Note at the end and that the output required is to add a new column.

Before we start note that `lag` in base R does not work on plain vectors.  It requires a time series.  For example

```
# wrong
with(DF, V2 / lag(V2, -12))
##  [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
## attr(,"tsp")
## [1] 13 27  1
```

**1) zoo** Convert `DF` to a zoo series and use `diff.zoo` with the indicated arguments.  `diff.zoo` supports `lag=` and `arith=` arguments.  If the latter is FALSE it uses division rather than subtraction for the diff.

```
library(zoo)

z <- read.zoo(DF, FUN = as.yearmon)
zz <- cbind(z, diff12 = diff(z, lag = 12, arith = FALSE))
zz
```

giving this zoo object (use fortify.zoo on it if you want a data frame as the result).

```
             z   diff12
Jan 2000 179.3       NA
Feb 2000 179.4       NA
Mar 2000 180.0       NA
Apr 2000 180.3       NA
May 2000 180.7       NA
Jun 2000 181.1       NA
Jul 2000 181.5       NA
Aug 2000 181.9       NA
Sep 2000 182.3       NA
Oct 2000 182.6       NA
Nov 2000 183.1       NA
Dec 2000 183.3       NA
Jan 2001 183.9 1.025655
Feb 2001 184.4 1.027871
Mar 2001 184.7 1.026111
```

**2) ts**  Another possibility is to use a ts series.  This only uses base R.

```
tt <- ts(DF$V2, start = c(2000, 1), frequency = 12)
cbind(tt, diff12 = tt / lag(tt, -12))
```

The result is this ts series:

```
            tt   diff12
Jan 2000 179.3       NA
Feb 2000 179.4       NA
Mar 2000 180.0       NA
Apr 2000 180.3       NA
May 2000 180.7       NA
Jun 2000 181.1       NA
Jul 2000 181.5       NA
Aug 2000 181.9       NA
Sep 2000 182.3       NA
Oct 2000 182.6       NA
Nov 2000 183.1       NA
Dec 2000 183.3       NA
Jan 2001 183.9 1.025655
Feb 2001 184.4 1.027871
Mar 2001 184.7 1.026111
```

**3) collapse**  The `fdiff` function in the collapse package can be  used with the `log=` argument.  Note that exp(log(x) - log(y)) equals x/y.

```
library(collapse)
ftransform(DF, diff12 = exp(fdiff(DF$V2, 12, log = TRUE)))
```

or

```
ftransform(DF, diff12 = V2 / flag(V2, 12))
```

**4) dplyr** The `lag` function in dplyr can be used; however, be very careful using it because it clobbers base R's `lag` and will result in numerous packages not working.  Safest is to exclude it when loading dplyr and then use `dplyr::lag` .  Also be aware that the `n=` argument of dplyr's `lag` has the opposite sign of the `lag` function in base R creating even more confusion.

```
library(dplyr, exclude = c("lag", "filter"))

DF %>% mutate(diff12 = V2 / dplyr::lag(V2, 12))
```

**5) Base R**  The ts solution above only uses base R but here is another base R solution.

```
transform(DF, diff12 = c(rep(NA, 12), tail(V2, -12) / head(V2, -12)))
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "2000-01: 179.300
2000-02: 179.400
2000-03: 180.000
2000-04: 180.300
2000-05: 180.700
2000-06: 181.100
2000-07: 181.500
2000-08: 181.900
2000-09: 182.300
2000-10: 182.600
2000-11: 183.100
2000-12: 183.300
2001-01: 183.900
2001-02: 184.400
2001-03: 184.700"

DF <- read.table(text = Lines, sep = ":")
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you for helping. I used way number 5. It runs fine.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data is like this:

```
x <- data.frame(month = c("2000-01", "2000-02", "2000-03", "2000-04", 
                          "2000-05", "2000-06", "2000-07", "2000-08",
                          "2000-09", "2000-10", "2000-11", "2000-12", 
                          "2001-01", "2001-02", "2001-03"),
                value = c(179.3, 179.4, 180, 180.3, 180.7, 181.1, 181.5, 
                          181.9, 182.3, 182.6, 183.1, 183.3, 183.9, 184.4, 
                          184.7))
```

You could run:

```
x$annual_chg <- x$value / dplyr::lag(x$value,12)


> x
    month value annual_chg
1  2000-01 179.3         NA
2  2000-02 179.4         NA
3  2000-03 180.0         NA
4  2000-04 180.3         NA
5  2000-05 180.7         NA
6  2000-06 181.1         NA
7  2000-07 181.5         NA
8  2000-08 181.9         NA
9  2000-09 182.3         NA
10 2000-10 182.6         NA
11 2000-11 183.1         NA
12 2000-12 183.3         NA
13 2001-01 183.9   1.025655
14 2001-02 184.4   1.027871
15 2001-03 184.7   1.026111
```

Comment: Thank you @g-grothendieck for catching that! I forgot about the difference between base `lag` and `dplyr::lag`, which I had loaded. Thank you for your comprehensive answer, always neat to see more alternatives. Enthusiastically upvoted.